# Qt - GUI freezing

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface

I wrote in C++ a solver for the 8-puzzle game, and now I'm trying to use Qt to give it a GUI.

Basically I have an underlying object of type "Board" which represents the board of the puzzle, and I have organized the GUI as a grid of QPushButton. Then I have a method updateUI which associates to every button the correct text, based on the Board. Something like

```
    for(int i=0; i<Board::MATRIX_DIM * Board::MATRIX_DIM; i++)
    {
        m_buttons[i]->setText(m_values[i]);
    }
```

In another method (solveGUI) I have

```
void MainWindow::solveGUI()
{
    m_game->solve();
    int solutionDepth = m_game->getSolutionDepth();
    Move *solutionMoves = m_game->getSolutionMoves();
    for(int i=0; i<solutionDepth; i++)
    {
        Move m = solutionMoves[i];
        m_board.performMove(m);     /* perform the move on the Board object */
        updateUI();       /* should update the GUI so that it represents the Board */
        Sleep(1000);
    }
}
```

where the first line (m_game->solve) takes some time. Then I obtain a list of the moves performed, in solutionMoves, and what I would like to do is showing this moves on the board, with some delay between a move and the next one. This method is called by my main, which looks like this:

```
QApplication app(argc, argv);
MainWindow w;
w.show();
w.solveGUI();

return app.exec();
```

The result is that the GUI hangs and, after some time, it displays only the solution, completely skipping the moves.

What am I missing? Thank you!

P.S. I don't think I need a different Thread for the solver because I want the solver to run *before* the solution is displayed. Is it right?

Comment: UIs are event based (this goes to the OS level, it's not a Qt thing). You need to redesign your solve function so that instead of sleeping, it returns right away after solving; then you can set up a timer (which provides events on the UI thread) to display the moves one at a time without hogging the UI thread.

Comment: Don't know if I understood what you said about redesigning my solve function... What it does is basically expanding the nodes of the search tree until it reaches the goal, and it works: on average it takes just a few milliseconds. Then, *after* this, I would like to start showing the moves.

Comment: I meant your `solveGUI` method, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Ok, I will try and post back in case I need some more help. Thanks!

Comment: Don't use `Sleep`. Use `QTimer` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's `app.exec()` that actually runs the main loop which handles all events, including displaying GUI. If you want to call `solve()` before that, it's OK, but if you want to actually display and update GUI before `exec()`, it's wrong. I'm not sure if it's totally impossible, but it's definitely not the right way to do it.

There are two ways around it. The more canonical way is to redesign a program using a `QTimer`. Then everything will be smooth and responsive. But that can be tedious sometimes. In your case it should be quite easy, though. Just save the results somewhere, and call a slot using a `QTimer` object every 1000 seconds - it will have the same effect as your `Sleep()`, but will keep everything responsive.

The other solution is to call your `solveGUI()` method after `exec()` starts its job. It can be done, for example, using `QTimer::singleShot()`:

```
QTimer::singleShot(0, &w, SLOT(showGUI()));
return app.exec();
```

Then, before each `Sleep()`, you should call `QApplication::processEvents()`, which basically allows you to temporary yield control, processing all pending events, including GUI updates. This approach is somewhat easier, but it's inferior since the GUI still freezes at each `Sleep()`. For example, if the user wants to exit the application, or if the window is needed to be repainted, it will cause uncomfortable GUI lags.

Answer (score 1):

You're stalling the main thread (which also does the event processing) and rendering it uncapable of responding to keyboard/mouse/window messages.

You should use an asynchronous timer operation instead of the sleep function: use a [QTimer](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtimer.html) to delay showing the next solution and avoid messages being left unanswered for too long.

Answer (score 1):

There is a nice [article of methods to keep the GUI responsive](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qq/qq27-responsive-guis.html) during processing loops. if it's not a complicated case I think, just insert `QCoreApplication::processEvents();` inside the long processing loops.

Answer (score 0):

try the following:

```
void MainWindow::Wait(int interval ) {

    QTime timer = new QTime;
    timer.restart();

    while(timer.elapsed() < interval) {
        QApplication::processEvents();
    }

}

...
 
for(...) { 

//wait 1 second (1000 milliseconds) between each loop run at first
Wait(1000);
...

}
...
```

not tested yet - but should work (maybe there is some cpu load)!