# QMetaObject::invokeMethod execution is postponed

Tags: c++, qt

I have a method of my class which calls `QMetaObject::invokeMethod`.
From the [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#ConnectionType-enum) I read that using Qt::DirectConnection should invoke the slot immediately.
On my code I seams to experience that the slot is called only at the end of the execution of my method. I have therefore tried to put a long sleep between the invokeMethod and the end of the function and I do see the slot being executed at the end of the sleep time.

```
void myTest(){
    QMetaObject::invokeMethod(obj, "MyMethod",
                              Qt::DirectConnection,
                              Q_ARG(QString, myString));
    for(int j=0;j<10;j++)
    {
            qDebug() << "j: "<< j;
            Sleep(1000);
    }
}
```

Any idea why invoke is waiting the end of the function?
I have also tried using `Qt::AutoConnection`

Comment: Is the object in the same thread?

Comment: Post an MVCE , including the `obj` class declaration and how you're calling `myTest()`.

Comment: @dtech it doesn't matter with direct connection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example `Sleep(1000);` is blocking the event loop then the slot can not be triggered.

To make it work there are 2 possible solutions:

1. Use a QTimer.
2. Before each `Sleep(1000);` call `QApplication::processEvents()`. This call will process all the pending events.

For more info you can read this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/26552350/8644816